# UITextField First responder, minimizing app and then restoring, cursor looks and text disappears during typing

Tags: ios, uitextfield

in my viewDidLoad I have this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.activityIndicator.hidden=YES;


    [self.userField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

If the cursor is in the userField and I minimize the app and then restore it it behaves odd, the text content of the field disappears as I type. Is there anyway to fix this? Do I have to resign the first responder before the app is minimised or something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move the statement `[self.userField becomeFirstResponder];` from the method `viewWillAppear` to the method `viewDidAppear` as -

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.userField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```